# Python: How to store string inputs on a array

Tags: python, arrays

Hi I would like to store strings on a array. This strings are produced in this loop:

```
while (count < ts ):
    dt=tb
    t1=count+180
    t2=t1+360
    dt1=dt+t1
    dt2=dt+t2
    slice=stream.slice(dt1, dt2)
    B=str(dt1)
    E=str(dt2)
    slice.write(station+'_'+comp[i]+'_'+B+'_'+E, format="MSEED")
    count = count + 360
    bb=[]
    name=station+B+'_'+E
    a=[str(name)]
    bb.append(a)
```

But it doesn't work. The variable name is from type:

```
name=2011-05-22T23:54:00.000000Z_2011-05-22T23:59:59.984000Z
```

And I would like to have an array like that:

```
bb=[2011-05-22T23:42:00.000000Z_2011-05-22T23:48:00.000000Z, 2011-05-22T23:48:00.000000Z_2011-05-22T23:54:00.000000Z, 2011-05-22T23:54:00.000000Z_2011-05-22T23:59:59.984000Z]
```

But what bb returns me is an array with the last element called:

```
bb=[2011-05-22T23:54:00.000000Z_2011-05-22T23:59:59.984000Z]
```

If I do it manually:

```
bb.append('2011-05-22T23:54:00.000000Z_2011-05-22T23:59:59.984000Z')
```

It works perfectly because I put the ''. But I need to it in a automatic way.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are declaring bb within the while loop. You probably will be getting the last one.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

Declare bb outside the loop and a will be a list. You will get a list of lists(not in the way you asked for)